# How can I deal with this encoding?

Tags: json, encoding, google-chrome

I'm now trying to parse chrome bookmarks, but I encounter a problem. the bookmarks snippet is presented as follow:

```
    {
        "date_added": "12915566290018721",
        "id": "16",
        "name": "hao123\uFF0D\uFF0D\u6211\u7684\u4E0A\u7F51\u4E3B\u9875",
        "type": "url",
        "url": "http://www.hao123.com/"
     }
```

the string coding corresponding to name field is stored as "hao123\uFF0D\uFF0D\u6211\u7684\u4E0A\u7F51\u4E3B\u9875", but it should be "hao123--我的上网主页" to provide to users. How can I transform "hao123\uFF0D\uFF0D\u6211\u7684\u4E0A\u7F51\u4E3B\u9875" to "hao123--我的上网主页"?

```
thanks!
```

Comment: What are you using to parse the JSON? If you're using Javascript directly, then it should "just work". If you're using some other library then you need to tell us which one.

Comment: Whoever had that bookmark, recommend them to repair their browser, and possibly reset all settings, because hao123 tends to install itself without user consent, as by-product of installation of other software, including many BaiDu-related products. It tends to inject itself as default page during opening, as homepage, as toolbar and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from looking at the [Jsoncpp source code](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/json__reader_8cpp_source.html#l00657), it looks like it should decode the string properly and you'll get a UTF-8 string back. If that is not what you're seeing, please post the code that you're actually using, and what you're getting back instead.

Comment: You are right, my code is :

     std::ifstream infile("Bookmarks");  

     Json::Value root;  
     Json::Reader reader;  
     bool ok = reader.parse(infile,root); 
     if(!ok)  
     {  
         return;  
     }  
  std::string name = root.get("name","").asString(); 
  cout<<name<<endl;

when I output it to a file, open it in VIM, the result is :
hao123锛嶏紞鎴戠殑涓婄綉涓婚〉
but if I open it in Microsoft word, it promoted me to select UTF8 encoding and get the right answer.    So I do think it is a UTF8 encoding one.

Comment: So I try this code, but it does not get the right answer, why:

  std::string name = root.get("name","").asString(); 
  cout<<name<<endl;

  int len=strlen(name.c_str())+1;
  WCHAR outName[MAX_PATH];
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), len, outName, len);

      wcout<<outName<<endl;

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code

```
   std::string name = root.get("name","").asString(); 

   USES_CONVERSION;

   std::wstring wstr_name(A2W_CP(name.c_str(), CP_UTF8));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at are UTF-16 code points in the string. Unless you have a JSON library that handles Unicode for you, consider iterating the string and looking for the escape sequence that denotes the UTF-16 code point "\u". From there you can transform the string to whatever encoding is necessary for it to output properly.

Comment: Thanks!   I use a Jsoncpp to parse it and get a C++ std::string, but I don't know how to transform it.  Is that any function like MultiByteToWideChar?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to transform the name field as std::string to wchar_t? 

or provide me relative materials.    thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks codeka, I solve the problem.

```
 std::string name = root.get("name","").asString(); 
 cout<<name<<endl;

 int len=strlen(name.c_str())+1;
 WCHAR outName[MAX_PATH];
// MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), len, outName, len);


 char outch[MAX_PATH];
 WCHAR * wChar=new WCHAR[len];
 wChar[0]=0;
 MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name.c_str(), len, wChar, len);
 WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wChar, len, outch , len, 0, 0);
 delete [] wChar;




  cout<<outch<<endl;
```

Thanks codeka & fbrereto again.

Answer (score 0):

Up is work. here is my code。

```html
        Json::Reader reader;
        Json::Value root;
        if (reader.parse(response, root))
        {
            if (root.isMember("data")&& root.isMember("msg"))
            {
                Json::Value data = root["data"];
                std::string str = root["msg"].asCString();
                std::string cstr = UnicodeToGB2312(str);
                AndroidSay("%s", cstr.c_str());
            }
        }
```

```html
string UnicodeToGB2312(std::string uData)
{
    int len = strlen(uData.c_str()) + 1;
    char outch[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR * wChar = new WCHAR[len];
    wChar[0] = 0;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, uData.c_str(), len, wChar, len);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wChar, len, outch, len, 0, 0);
    delete[] wChar;
    char* pchar = (char*)outch;
    return pchar;
}
```